# How to make a new DataFrame in sparkR

Tags: sparkr

In sparkR I have `data` as a DataFrame.
I can attach one entry in `data` like this:

```
newdata <- filter(data, data$column == 1)
```

How can I attach more than just one?

 Say I want to attach all elements in the vector `list <- c(1,6,10,11,14)` or if `list` is a DataFrame `1 6 10 11 14`.

```
newdata <- filter(data, data$column == list)
```

If I do it like this I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ultimately trying to filter a spark DataFrame by a list of unique values, you can do this with a `merge` operation. If you are talking about going from a long to a wide data format, you need to ensure there are the same number of observations for each 'level' of the factor variable you are considering. If you want to subset a Spark dataframe by columns, you could also use a select statement, or build up a select statement by pasting data$blah into and then do the `eval(parse(text=bigTextObject))` as @Wannes suggested. Maybe a function that generates a big `select` statement is what you want (if you are filtering by column name)...a `merge` is what you want if you are trying to extract values from a single column.

From what I understand, it seems as if you want to take a big Spark DataFrame with lots of columns and only take the ones you are interested in, as indicated by `list` in your question.

Here is a little function to generate the spark `select` statement:

```
list<- c(1,2,5,8,90,200)
listWithDataPrePended<- paste0('data', '$', list)
gettingCloser<- noquote(paste0(listWithDataPrePended, collapse = ','))
finalSelectStatement<- noquote(paste("select(data,", gettingCloser, ")"))
finalData<- eval(parse(text=finalSelectStatement))
finalData<- SparkR::collect(finalData)
```

Maybe this is what you're looking for...maybe not. Nonetheless, I hope it's helpful.

Good luck, 
nate

Answer (score 0):

The == list will not work, nor %in% list which would make more sense, but you can do it as follows (I have included an example data.frame):

```
dataLocal <- data.frame(column=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10)),column2=1:30)
data      <- createDataFrame(sqlContext,dataLocal)
newdata   <- filter(data, (data$column == 1)|(data$column == 2))
```

or more in general (now your list2 can be of arbitrary length)

```
list2 <- c(1,2)
listEquals  <- paste("(data$column == ",list2,")",sep="")
checkEquals <- paste(listEquals,collapse="|")
func  <- paste("filter(data, ",checkEquals,")",sep="")
newdata <- eval(parse(text=func))
```

Do not forget to run

```
collect(newdata)
```

to check the result.

Comment: All of this works fine for a vector 'list2' with a small length. But if we have a vector 'list2' where length(list2)=10000 I get this message in sparkR: error in evaluating the argument 'condition' in selecting a method for function 'filter': Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?