# To collect DataFrames in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

I have 100 DataFrame's in sparkR.

```
us = filter(pg, pg$user_id==1)
us = filter(pg, pg$user_id==2)
....
us = filter(pg, pg$user_id == 100)
```

I want to collect them in a new DataFrame. One way to do this is this way

```
for(i in 1:100){
us=filter(pg, pg$user_id==i)
all=unionAll(all, us)
}
```

Now 'all' is a DataFrame and contains 100 of these other DataFrames. This take some time to run in SparkR and I wonder if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: what about `do.call(rbind, lapply(1:100, function(x) filter(pg, pg$user_id==x)))` ?

Comment: Good idea @ColonelBeauvel, but rbind should be unionAll in SparkR setting.

Comment: @Ole , so `do.call(unionAll, lapply(1:100, function(x) filter(pg, pg$user_id==x)))` :) ?

Comment: Where I use my method it took 93 sec and using lapply-method it took 95 sec. However the running-time is not a huge problem for me in this case :o)

Comment: But why don't you immediately use filter(pg,pg$user_id %in% 1:100), without actually using %in% but the answer on your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743612/how-to-make-a-new-dataframe-in-sparkr

Comment: Yes now it's even faster. Say 'us' is a DataFrame with ID = 1,...,100 and 'height'= 188,201,158,.... Then how can I take the sum of all the heights? In sparkR one can't just do this sum(us$height).

Comment: If sum does not work, then take a look at the agg function although this works on groupedData and otherwise I would recommend to use sparkSQL.