# Faster way to use filter in sparkR

Tags: sparkr

I have a DataFrame 'data' which contains user_id's. To get all user_id=1 I simply do this

```
filter(data, data$user_id==1)
```

Say I want to make a new DataFrame 'new_data' containing the first 10 user_id's namely user_id= 1, 2 , 3 ,..., 10.

One way to it in SparkR is

```
newdata <- unionAll(filter(data, data$user_id==1), filter(data, data$user_id==2))
for(j in 3:10){
newdata<- unionAll(newdata, filter(data, data$user_id==j) )
}
```

This works fine, however, it can take time for large j. There must be a smarter and more simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possible solutions. First of al %in% is not supported in SparkR, but a naive way to fix this approach is the answer on the question [How to make a new DataFrame in sparkR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743612/how-to-make-a-new-dataframe-in-sparkr).

For the other approaches, I provide a minimal example DataFrame:
    df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4),
                     age = c(21,23,33,21))

```
data <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df)
```

A second approach only works when you want to take the first ID's (or at least successive ID's). Then you can do the following

newdata <- filter(data, data$ID < 3)
collect(newdata)

More generally you can join your data with the ID's you want to keep. This is easier when you want to keep non-successive ID's, but when you have successive ID's, it will be slower than the previous approach:

```
toJoin <- data.frame(IDs = c(1,3))
toJoin <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, toJoin)

newdata <- join(data,toJoin, data$ID == toJoin$IDs)
newdata$IDs <- NULL
collect(newdata)
```